# Python Extract values from string and move onto next

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to extract strings that fit between the patterns '{"comments_disabled":' and '}},'
and then append whatever fits between these two patterns. (There could be 100+ occurances that match between these patterns.

The problem is that the code below just keeps extracting the first occurrence, how do I make it ignore what it previously appended to the userpost list and move onto the next?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = urlopen("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/fun/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")
title = soup.title
script = str(soup.findAll('script', type="text/javascript"))

userpost = list()

for text in script:
userpost.append(script[script.find('{"comments_disabled":')/
:script.find('}},')+2])
```

Comment: can you update sample input along with expected output?

Comment: @MaheshKaria Updated with sample input the out put string is fairly long, but you can attain it from running this script :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
userpost = re.findall(r'{"comments disabled":(.*?)}},', script)
```

Tested script:

```
import re

script = '''
{"comments disabled": one two }},
alpha beta
{"comments disabled": three four }},
{"comments disabled":
five six
}},
'''

userpost = re.findall(r'{"comments disabled":(.*?)}},', script, re.DOTALL)
print(userpost)
```

Output:

```
[' one two ', ' three four ', '\nfive six\n']
```

Comment: When i run this with the data in 'script', no variable is created in variable explorer. Any reason why? I've updated my post with how the script data is generated :) @Robᵩ

Comment: What is "*variable explorer*"?

Comment: @jacksmart - FYI, I have updated my answer to account for the possibility that `{"comments disabled":` and `}}` might occur on different lines.